# Movie Identification: Humanoid Monster/Alien in a bed, 80s/90s, Sci-Fi/Horror

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

I've been looking for the name of a movie for over a year now, this is my last chance.

Here are the details which I remember:

- I watched this movie a few times when I was younger, I'd say 80s to early 90s. Might be early 80s when the movie actually came out.
- It had an alien/humanoid/moster that was always in a bed covered until towards middle/end. He looked normal from waste up its what was covered that was monster/alien.
- There was a swimming pool with slight fog in the movie at some point - if I recall correctly.
- It was slightly humorous but not a full-on comedy.
- I remember this alien/humanoid thing that was always in the bed - was a big bed.
- There may have been one scene where there were a few scantly clad women around the monster/alein thing. Someone walked into the room and the covers was moving about then the humanoid/alien/monster popped up, then the girls popped up besides him. Party scene??
- The rest of the family was normal looking - if I recall correctly.
- It was just the father who was like this.
- The monster/alien might be the uncle or grandpa

**What is the name of this movie?**

I'm hoping that someone has seen this and remembers it so I can see it again.

Comment: This fits the description almost perfectly; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back

Comment: If it was a wheelchair instead of a bed it could be Charles Bands's "Head of the Family", (1996).  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116503/

Comment: Could you try to make the title a bit more descriptive and 'searchable'? It would really help the question's exposure.

Comment: Really Richard? Thanks for a new movie to watch Will. Thanks for the edit and help Mooz!

Comment: I think Richard meant "Return of the Jedi", not TESB.

Comment: Are you sure ya'll both meant "Spaceballs", Omegacron?

Comment: OMG I have literally had this same exact question/movie in my mind for my entire adult life!!! I saw it when I was a kid and can always remember the bed scene where the kids walk in on all the adults, but never knew what movie this was. Can't believe another person in the world had the exact same movie on the tip of his tongue. This question & answer made my day.

Answer (score 6):

This is the 1986 film [Terrorvision](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092074/) - I had been trying to find the title for forever, myself.

Similarities:

- The movie is from 1986
- The movie contains a monster that can imitate the heads of the people it eats. In one scene it imitates five different people poking their heads out from under the blanket of a single, large bed at a swinger's party. The blanket is undulating wildly through the whole scene, and there are two kids looking in through the door
- There is a large, indoor swimming pool completely covered in smoke
- The monster eats and imitates the heads of the father and the grandfather of the family

Differences:

- The bed scene is relatively brief, and it's the only time the monster is in a bed
- The monster is seen completely many times before and after the bed scene
- The monster is not even remotely humanoid
- It's most definitely an over the top, full-on comedy
- The monster eats the whole family

You can watch the full film online below (NSFW - Horror comedy)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer?

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer.